# O que são e como funcionam slots e "scoped slots" em Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Em Vue.js podemos passar descendentes a um componente da seguinte maneira:

```
<meu-componente>
    <div>Um descendente</div>
    <div>Outro descendente</div>
</meu-componente>
```

De que maneira funciona isso e qual a relação com `<slot></slot>` e *scoped slots* para receber descendência de outro componente e passar `props` aos elementos descendentes?

Um `slot` pode ter descendência inicial que é substituída por futura descendência caso haja sem ter de se usar um `v-if` ou `v-show`?

Como saber que conteúdo deve ir para que slot no caso de um componente ter vários?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> De que maneira funciona o `<slot></slot>` e *scoped slots* para receber descendência de outro componente e passar `props` aos elementos descendentes?

Quando um componente possui slot(s), é possível injetar conteúdo nele a partir do componente pai, sem a necessidade de se utilizar `props`. Por exemplo:

```js
var MeuComponente = Vue.component('meu-componente', {
    template: '<div class="meu-componente"><h1>{{ header }}</h1><slot></slot></div>',
    data() { return { header: 'Isto vem de dentro' } }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Isto vem de fora'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <meu-componente>
    {{ message }}
  </meu-componente>
</div>
```

Repare que `message` pertence ao componente de fora (a raiz/app do Vue, neste caso), enquanto o cabeçalho renderiza o valor de uma variável interna ao componente.

> Como saber que conteúdo deve ir para que slot no caso de um componente ter vários?

Você pode usar múltiplos slots simplesmente dando um atributo name para cada, e passando o conteúdo numa tag HTML com atributo `slot` apontando para aquele name. Na definição do componente fica assim, por exemplo:

```
<h1>{{ header }}</h1>
<slot name="abaixo-do-h1"></slot>
<h2>Outro header</h2>
<slot name="abaixo-do-h2"></slot>
```

No uso fica assim:

```
<meu-componente>
    <div slot="abaixo-do-h1>Isto vai abaixo do h1</div>
    <div slot="abaixo-do-h2>Isto vai abaixo do h2</div>
</meu-componente>
```

> Um slot pode ter descendência inicial que é substituída por futura descendência caso haja sem ter de se usar um v-if ou v-show?

Sim! Se você não passar um conteúdo para determinado slot a partir do componente externo, o conteúdo do slot definido no componente interno será exibido. Funciona como um conteúdo *default*.

Answer (score 5):

Slots do  Vue.js é especialmente para você inserir html extra dentro do componente

Exemplo:

Esta é a criação de um componente com slots, no exemplo a seguir você tem uma estrutura de modal completa para ser aberto e fechado dependendo da ação recebida via props (no exemplo mostro apenas a parte do html, beleza)

```
let modal = `

    <div class="modal">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <slot name="heade"></slot>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-content">
        <slot name="content"></slot>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-action">
        <slot name="action"></slot>
    </div>

</div>

`
```

O motivo de fazer slots é justamente para o conteudo aguardado pelo compoente ser de acordo com o escopo de cada situação, isso é, o componente não terá um conteúdo fixo para sempre, ele recebera pedaços de conteúdo via slot e sera colocado dentro do slot em ordem

Atribuindo conteúdo para slot:

```
<modal>

    <div slot="header">
        <!--todo conteudo header aqui-->
    </div>

    <div slot="content">
        <!--todo conteudo content aqui-->
    </div>

    <div slot="action">
        <!--todo conteudo action aqui-->
    </div>

</modal>
```

Dessa forma você prepara o componente para receber conteúdo organizadamente e com possível formatação pré-configurada. Espero ter ajudado!